# run java application as background process

Tags: java, windows, service, windows-services

i have made an application using java....when i am installing it on my computer ...i want it to run as ***background process*** instead of application...if any user try Task manager...then he can not found it in application....it should no listed in application list...it is there in process list....
so please tell me how can i do this ...as soon as possible....?

Answer (score 5):

My work uses this:
http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/download.jsp

It works well for them and has a lot of functionality.

Comment: its limited for commercial especially win64 bit

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/.

There is a comparison table for [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/), [JSW](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/), [ACD](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/) and [L4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: this is completely free including win64! nice!