# i want a java application run in background (like skipe or gtalk)

Tags: java, windows

I  made a java program for a pop-up from time to time by running a batch file. Application is working fine but after running the application(Batch file) we are able to see the cmd prompt in taskbar(minimize state), but i want the application run in background (like skype or gtalk).
Please help me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: refer these links,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146696/run-java-application-as-background-process

http://www.coderanch.com/t/232702/threads/java/running-java-application-background

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app

Answer (score 1):

Use a vbs script to invoke the batch script it would hide the window

`CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "yourbatchname.bat",0,True`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you launch it using javaw (instead of java).

Relevant portion from [the first link from the first search](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-vs-javaw-vs-javaws/) here:

> This is provided as a helper so that application launches its own GUI window and will not launch a console. Whenever we want to run a GUI based application and don’t require a command console, we can use this as application launcher.

I hope this helps you.